# Find node_modules on Ubuntu 13.04 (-g)

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, sails.js, node-modules

I want to update my module *sails* from NPM.

But I can't find it, I'm not a pro Ubuntu/Linux so maybe there is a trick here.

```
user@tripanalyzer:~$ npm remove -g sails
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "sails"
user@tripanalyzer:~$ sails -v
info: v0.9.4
```

Where could it be if he is not here ? ^^
I probably installed it using "sudo" command. But I tried a sudo npm remove... and still the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't supply the `-g` argument when you installed `sails`, the package isn't installed as a global package, and thus cannot be removed with the `-g` keyword. From the warning message I would say this is the case.

Where exactly the package is installed then depends on "where" in your filesystem you were when you installed it.

If you have a project which uses the `sails` package, then check to see if the project has any locale nodes modules folder (or similar).

Comment: I'm sure to have used the -g command when I installed it! But your answer is probably correct, I just don't understand where it's installed, there is a way to know that?

Comment: You could try a simple search. Like `sudo find / -name 'sails'`

Comment: Yes, thanks! I found it in /usr/lib/node_modules/ and updated it ;)